# cyclomatic complexity of entire project solution.by not using directly any software

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cyclomatic-complexity

**Calculate Cyclomatic Complexity using c# code.**
I am developing an application, that will take solution name from user and will show cyclomatic complexity of that solution in c#. please help me.
I am taking solution name from the user and i have to show the cyclomatic complexity list to the user. how can i do this?

Comment: You search for an application you intend to write? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for certain software are off-topic, but I can tell you that there already exist visual studio extensions for that purpose.

Comment: i know that there is visual studio extensons for this purpose, but i have to do it using code. if you can help ?

Comment: like if any how i can write some code that will pass the solution name as input and open that tool, and then by going through the report generated, i can show the list of functions and classes that are having more than 5 cyclomatic complexity. this is my task.

Comment: Which part do you need to write? The calculation of the complexity or displaying the results in VS? Please be more specific. Nobody will write a whole application for you here.

Comment: calculation of complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics NuGet package could provide many useful metrics including CyclomaticComplexity.

Comment: Welcome to Sstackoverflow, please search the site before asking a question, Someone may have asked this or a similar question before you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but i did it using Metrics.exe  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-generate-code-metrics-data?view=vs-2019 through command line. and it was successful.